Tomcat JVM crash EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)
I'm getting this error now and then running a java 21/spring 6 based application on Tomcat 21. Not sure how to troubleshoot.
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000002385e05db66, pid=18324, tid=7996

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.2+13 (21.0.2+13) (build 21.0.2+13-LTS)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.2+13 (21.0.2+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 j  jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setRequest(Ljakarta/servlet/ServletRequest;)V+0

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\XXX\apache-tomcat-11.0.0-M18\bin\hs_err_pid18324.log
[79.405s][warning][os] Loading hsdis library failed

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues

Disconnected from server


Upgrade to Java 21.0.3 and see if that fixes it. This is a low-level error where an attempt was made to write (or read) from the wrong memory location.
